# ios provisioning profile cannot transfer to device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

I recently downloaded an ios provisioning profile to my new macbook. In the organizer library it says the profile is valid; however, when I try to add it to my iPad, it says "MyIpad is not included in this profile." This ipad has already been added to the development portal, and it will not let me add it to the portal again. What should I do to allow me to run my app on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple provisioning profiles for an app: the Store provisioning profile (these don't have any devices associated with them), an ADHOC provisioning profile and a DEBUG / Development provisioning profile.

Just because you added your iPad to the development portal doesn't mean it's part of the provisioning profile for your app.

Go to your Provisioning Portal in Apple and click "edit" on the provisioning profile for your app, then look at the list of devices and make certain they are *checked* for your app.

Here's what it looks like on my side:

[image: Make Certain Devices You Want Are Added]

As you can see, I have exactly two devices out of 30 possible devices set to be allowed this app's ADHOC build.  In my case this (old) provisioning profile is "expired", but after adding new devices, you need to click the "Generate" button and a new provisioning profile is generated. Do not forget to download the new profile and add it to your Xcode organizer.  If it doesn't work immediately, restart Xcode and by then you should be all set.

Comment: let's give them credit though -- I can see Apple is trying to make it easier for developers.

Comment: True - we can give them that.